# Parameter 4 of constructor in ApplicationUserService required a bean of type 'ConfirmationToken' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security

I am creating a complete user login and registration back-end system with email verification and usage of PostgreSQL to store the user's credentials. I am sending the user's credentials and e-mail address via Postman in POST request, and then I am generating an e-mail with a link for activation that lasts 15 minutes.

I've come to a point where I am dealing with a bug, in which I am posting my payload via Postman, the e-mail gets registered but if the time limit expires I can't send another e-mail since the latter has already been registered in my DB. To debug this, I am currently modifying my service class as follows:

**Registration Service Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.registration;

import com.andrekreou.iot.auth.ApplicationUser;
import com.andrekreou.iot.auth.ApplicationUserService;
import com.andrekreou.iot.email.EmailSender;
import com.andrekreou.iot.registration.token.ConfirmationToken;
import com.andrekreou.iot.registration.token.ConfirmationTokenService;
import com.andrekreou.iot.security.ApplicationUserRole;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationService {

    private final ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;
    private final EmailValidator emailValidator;
    private final ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;
    private final EmailSender emailSender;

    public String register(RegistrationRequest request) {
        boolean isValidEmail = emailValidator.
                test(request.getEmail());
        if (!isValidEmail) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email not valid");
        }


        String token = applicationUserService.signUpUser(
                new ApplicationUser(
                        request.getFirstName(),
                        request.getLastName(),
                        request.getEmail(),
                        request.getPassword(),
                        ApplicationUserRole.USER
                )
        );

        String link = "https://localhost:8443/api/v1/registration/confirm?token=" + token;

        emailSender.send(
                request.getEmail(),
                buildEmail(request.getFirstName(),
                        link));

        return token;
    }

    @Transactional
    public String confirmToken(String token) {
        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = confirmationTokenService
                .getToken(token)
                .orElseThrow(() ->
                        new IllegalStateException("token not found"));

        if (confirmationToken.getConfirmedAt() != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("email already confirmed");
        }

        LocalDateTime expiredAt = confirmationToken.getExpiresAt();

        if (expiredAt.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("token expired");
        }

        confirmationTokenService.setConfirmedAt(token);
        applicationUserService.enableApplicationUser(
                confirmationToken.getApplicationUser().getEmail());
        return "confirmed";
    }

    private String buildEmail(String name, String link) {
        return " HTML CODE";
    }
}
```

**Confirmation Token Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.registration.token;

import com.andrekreou.iot.auth.ApplicationUser;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
public class ConfirmationToken {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "confirmation_token_sequence",
            sequenceName = "confirmation_token_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "confirmation_token_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String token;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime expiresAt;

    private LocalDateTime confirmedAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(
            nullable = false,
            name = "app_user_id"
    )
    private ApplicationUser applicationUser;

    public ConfirmationToken(String token,
                             LocalDateTime createdAt,
                             LocalDateTime expiresAt,
                             ApplicationUser applicationUser) {
        this.token = token;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.expiresAt = expiresAt;
        this.applicationUser = applicationUser;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUserService class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.auth;

import com.andrekreou.iot.registration.RegistrationRequest;
import com.andrekreou.iot.registration.RegistrationService;
import com.andrekreou.iot.registration.token.ConfirmationToken;
import com.andrekreou.iot.registration.token.ConfirmationTokenRepository;
import com.andrekreou.iot.registration.token.ConfirmationTokenService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG =
            "User with email %s not found";

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;
    private final ConfirmationTokenRepository confirmationTokenRepository;
    private final ConfirmationToken confirmationToken;
    private final RegistrationService registrationService;
    private final RegistrationRequest request;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() ->
                        new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(
                                String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG, email))));
    }

    public String signUpUser(ApplicationUser applicationUser){
        boolean mailExists = isMailExists(applicationUser);

        boolean tokenExists = isTokenExists(confirmationToken);

        if (mailExists && !tokenExists) {
            registrationService.register(request);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("email already taken");
        }

        String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(applicationUser.getPassword());

        applicationUser.setPassword(encodedPassword);

        userRepository.save(applicationUser);

        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(
                token,
                LocalDateTime.now(),
                LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(15),
                applicationUser
        );

        confirmationTokenService.saveConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);

        return token;
    }

    private boolean isTokenExists(ConfirmationToken confirmationToken){
        return confirmationTokenRepository.findByToken(confirmationToken.getToken()).isPresent();
    }

    private boolean isMailExists(ApplicationUser applicationUser) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(applicationUser.getEmail()).isPresent();
    }

    public int enableApplicationUser(String email) {
        return userRepository.enableAppUser(email);
    }
}
```

I've created two boolean variables which check if the mail exists in my DB and if the e-mail token doesn't. When these two conditions are true, I want to send the e-mail confirmation again back to the user. But I am dealing with the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 4 of constructor in com.andrekreou.iot.auth.ApplicationUserService required a bean of type 'com.andrekreou.iot.registration.token.ConfirmationToken' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.andrekreou.iot.registration.token.ConfirmationToken' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I know that this is a common error, but I don't know how to address it. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the bean for `ConfirmationToken` defined? BTW: I find it highly suspicious this is a field, when you also have a `ConfirmationTokenService` **and** `ConfirmationTokenRepository` (similar goes for `RegistrationRequest`), as both seem request-related, and not something that should be fixed for all calls into this service.

Comment: What does your `ConfirmationToken`  look like? According to the error, it's not a Spring bean, so I don't think it should be in your fields/constructor.

Comment: @g00glenoob Added the class for confirmation token. Tried to add the NoArgsConstructor annotation but that doesn't work!!!

Comment: @Alex_Pap Can you explain why you have `ConfirmationToken` as a field?

Comment: @g00glen00b indeed, that was a mistake from a previous try that forgot to remove. But for some reason I still can't place the instantiation of `confirmation token` in the parameter of the boolean method. Instead I can place the following `boolean tokenExists = isTokenExists(new ConfirmationToken());` which throws the following exception -> "The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle". I will update my question with the class that this problem occurs.

Comment: @Alex_Pap The problem with the `isTokenExists()` call is unrelated to the error though. The reason you get the error is because both your `ApplicationUserService` and your `RegistrationService` depend on each other. Try to break this cyclic dependency by refactoring your code. For the problem with your `isTokenExists()` method, you'll have to explain what exactly you want to do. There is no token in `signupUser()` so I have no clue where you want to get it from. However, the comment section on Stack Overflow isn't the best way to answer this.